# I'm getting empty button name error when I use clearInput attribute for ionic-input tag in WAVE extension result. Did anyone face similar issue?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm using ionic-input tag with clearInput attribute. when I do auditing using wave extension for my website, i'm getting empty button error. That is because of icon 'x' to clear input, since icon doesn't have name wave is showing error. How can I solve this issue?
 Actual code is: `<ion-input id="input-name" formControlName="name" clearInput></ion-input>`

resultant in browser: 
`<ion-input _ngcontent-qcw-c39="" clearinput="" formcontrolname="name" id="input-name" ng-reflect-clear-input="" ng-reflect-name="name" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid sc-ion-input-md-h sc-ion-input-md-s md hydrated ion-untouched ion-pristine ion-invalid">
<input class="native-input sc-ion-input-md" aria-labelledby="ion-input-8-lbl" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" name="ion-input-8">
<button type="button" class="input-clear-icon sc-ion-input-md" tabindex="-1"></button>
</ion-input>`

Comment: can you please add your piece of code. Remember always add your code wherever you get error without it nobody could understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Property **clearInput** on **ion-input** take boolean value either true or false. By default its value is set to false. 
Example of ion-input is -

```
<ion-input type="text" [clearInput]="true" placeholder="Enter value"></ion-input>
```